# Adding monthly variable charges to PayPal plan agreements

Tags: paypal

I'm trying to develop my subscription module and I'm still in the design phase. 
Before I continue designing I'd like to know if it is possible for PayPal to allow me to add charges to a persons plan during the month.

IE. Going over your minutes on your cell phone plans makes your monthly charge go from A to A+B where A is the monthly charge and B is the supplemental charge.

In my circumstance it would be more a feature based where clients might have to add and remove features to their subscription on a semi regular interval. (New employee joins their office incurring a new charge which will be added to their subscription until the employee leaves)

Should I be using plans or another object when talking to PayPal?

Answer (score 0):

[Billing Agreements / Reference Transactions](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECReferenceTxns/) would be fine, or you could look into the [Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-accounts/integration-guide/ACIntroduction/) platform, specifically [Preapproval](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Preapproval_API_Operation/) and [Pay](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/).

I would recommend going with billing agreements through [Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/) and then using DoReferenceTransaction to process payments.  [DoReferenceTransaction](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoReferenceTransaction_API_Operation_NVP/) also works with [Payments Pro](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/WPWebsitePaymentsPro/) transactions if you ever end up using that, too.

If you happen to be working with PHP, my [PHP class library for PayPal](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library) will make all of these API calls very simple for you.